# PHP CURL cookie not sent in the website but works in the localhost test

Tags: php, curl, cookies, httprequest

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"denial=93a7a7e8b5af9f19a6df5e9850f8a64a;");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$the_source = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $the_source;
curl_close($ch);
```

The code works in my localhost, but not work in the real site, i have check the CURL is installed and works when using post method but not get method.
keep googling for hours but no solution yet. any help is appreciate.

Comment: currently is Debian 6, i try to  disable Mod_security module, also can't work, i wonder if that the CURL version is 7.21.0 is too old to handle CURLOPT_COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

It could be server depended problem. Or some 3rd tools on the server.

For example [this issue](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13011) looks similar.

The problem was that hosting use special "php protection system [suhosin](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13011)" that encrypt the session (session cookies) so the CURLOPT_COOKIE does not work.

The solution was to disable *suhosin.session.encrypt* parameter in /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini file:

```
suhosin.session.encrypt = off
```

Did you try to look for the answer in the server os community ? Do you know what "specail" php tools on the server installed ? Describe this in your question.

Comment: my OS is debian, i added suhosin.session.encrypt = off to my php.ini, but still not work...